# Custom metadata types - Deletion & access

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata

I have 2 questions on Custom Metadata type records:

- Is it possible to delete custom metadata records in a subscriber org? I can delete it in the packaging org but how can I send this deletion signal to the subscriber org apart from releasing/installing the whole package? What is the alternative?
- For a Protected type of Custom Metadata (which allows access to its object only through its own namespaced apex code) is it possible to package the records as a patch and install it in the subscriber org? Would such records installed as a patch be accessible from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete custom metadata records in a subscriber org?

No. The records cannot be deleted by a subscriber, as noted in [this table](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm).

> I can delete it in the packaging org but how can I send this deletion signal to the subscriber org apart from releasing/installing the whole package?

You need to upload a new version.

> What is the alternative?

There isn't one.

> For a Protected type of Custom Metadata (which allows access to its object only through its own namespaced apex code) is it possible to package the records as a patch and install it in the subscriber org?

You can change existing records, but cannot add or delete records in a patch.

> Would such records installed as a patch be accessible from the code?

You can't add or remove records in a patch. It needs to be a full version release. Once upgraded, they'll be visible as normal.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question to make it clearer, Adrian. Thank you for the answers, sfdcfox. Appreciate a lot.